Is there ambiguity in the following sentence or did I misunderstand it?
I ran across the following sentence while reading Japanese teaching materials. The context is that a teacher is explaining to students how to draw a parallelogram. The book has the following recommendation for an exercise in which students are tasked with drawing a parallelogram ABCD from a side BC and an angle of 70°:
教師が黒板で、辺BC をかき、70゜のところに点をとって辺AB をかくところまでを、1つ1つ児童に確認させながら示していき、続きをどうかいたかを発表させ、まとめていく。
What I don't understand is the 1つ1つ児童に確認させながら示していき part, more specifically, I am not sure I understand who the subject (and what the object) of 示していき is. Is it the teacher that needs to show something, or is it the student? I understand 1つ1つ児童に確認させながら to mean "Have each student individually check..." though I don't fully understand what 確認 is referring to here.
In this sentence, is there some sort of ambiguity (maybe to be determined from context), or is it just me misunderstanding something?

The idea is to have the teacher have each individual student confirm for themselves what the teacher is doing at the board.

I don't get the 70゜のところに点をとって辺AB をかくところまでを part...

1つ1つ refers to each step of the drawing (1. BCを書く; 2. 点を取る; 3. ABを書く). Not to be confused with each student (=1人1人の生徒).

@naruto Ah, thank you very much this was confusing me as well.


What I don't understand is the 1つ1つ児童に確認させながら示していき part

Maybe because this is not a "part."
What is a part here is:
教師が … 辺BC をかき、70゜のところに点をとって辺AB をかくところまで を … 示していき、…
And while doing the above, the teacher is 1つ1つ児童に確認させる.

I understand 1つ1つ児童に確認させながら to mean "Have each student individually check..."

"Check" is not the best way to translate 確認 here. It's to "confirm," "review," "validate."

what 確認 is referring to here.

Students acknowledging or demonstrating their understanding of what the teacher presented so far, per teacher's request.
I don't think there is an ambiguity in Japanese, but I can see ambiguity arising from the use of the word "check" in English to describe the students' task. It is, of course, the teacher checking the students, not the other way.

Ah so the subject of 確認させる is the teacher, not the pupil? Did you infer this from 幼児 being marked by に?

I did not infer anything. The sentence starts with 教師が. が is the subject marker, 教師 is the subject. It's so straightforward.

Ah that makes a lot of sense, I think I forgot about it while reading the rest of the sentence, thank you!
